# Which version of anaconda works on OSX El Capitan? And how do I get it?

Tags: download, installation, anaconda

I cannot upgrade to Sierra at the moment (IT policy), but I'd really like to work with anaconda on OSX.  Is there way to get an earlier version, or is there a way to solve the security issue:

~/anaconda$ open Navigator.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/cuz/anaconda/Navigator.app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macOS Sierra was released publicly on September 20, 2016. If you look at the [Anaconda changelogs](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/changelog#id5), it seems like version 4.1.1 (2016-07-08) was the latest one for OS X El Capitan because the next Anaconda update: 4.2.0 (2016-09-28) was released just after Sierra.

You can download Anaconda 4.1.1 or any older release from the Anaconda [archive page](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/).
For Mac OS X, you have a .pkg and a .sh installer, for a graphical installer download the one with .pkg extension.

Comment: That is awesome!  Thank you so much.